# Is WCF the correct approach for this generic SOAP message?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, wcf

A third party wishes to send us SOAP messages.

It is necessary that everything between the `<s:Body></s:Body>` element in our response is under our control.

After a few hours of research it seems that WCF messages will wrap the response in an xml element with the name of the WCF method.

Is there a way around this using WCF? Or is there a better, different altogether approach?

Comment: See if System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriter helps you.  BodyWriter is an abstract type that exposes a protected abstract method named OnWriteBodyContents.

Comment: Can you give some example for exactkly what you want? With the current details you have provided, I would like to suggest you to explore MessageContracts to have full control over the message.

Comment: @MilanRaval
So instead of `<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <TestMessageResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <TestMessageResult>hello</TestMessageResult>
    </TestMessageResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>`



Instead I would like 
 `<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
  hello
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>`

Comment: see this as well - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347789.aspx

Comment: Is this an absolute core part of your system or just a complementary, no so relevant functionallity ? If it doesn't require the flexibility and power of WCF I would go for a custom made connection where you can define the message completely by yourself in a template file. Just let me know if you are interested in this approach.

Comment: I suggest you try [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) as your receiver, it is fast and there are no configuration files.

Answer (score 2):

Try to define it as a bare service:

```
[SoapDocumentService(Use = SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
```